# Sum of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation

A friend challenged me to solve this, I tried and gave up and turned out he didn't know the answer too but this was given to him as a homework.

The question is to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-3)^k \binom{2n}{2k}$ in terms of $n >= 1$.

Can I get some help ? Thanks !

Comment: You haven't shown any effort. Please edit the question to include what you have tried.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Help us help you!

Comment: As per hints, recall that$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_k=\sum_{k=0}^n\color{red}{a_{2k}}+a_{2k+1}$$

Comment: Actually this was not my homework, i was just wandering....

Comment: Seems like your friend wanted to trick you into doing his homework :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick for doing this. We'd like to deal with a binomial expansion, but the $2k$ throws everything off. Try to reparametrize:
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}(-3)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}(i\sqrt{3})^{2k}=\sum_{m=0\textrm{ even}}^{2n}\binom{2n}{m}(i\sqrt{3})^m$$
Now we're getting somewhere. This is half the terms of a binomial sum; we're just missing the odd terms. That is, we know that
$$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{2n}=\sum_{m=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{m}(i\sqrt{3})^m=S(n)+\sum_{m=0\textrm{ odd}}^{2n}\binom{2n}{m}(i\sqrt{3})^m.$$
The last term is purely imaginary while $S(n)$ is purely real, so
$$S(n)=\textrm{Re}[(1+i\sqrt{3})^{2n}]=\textrm{Re}[(2e^{i\pi/3})^{2n}]=4^n\cos(2\pi n/3).$$

Comment: Great thanks, do you mean Re instead of Im ?

Comment: Sure do, thanks for pointing that out.